# Is it still possible to use Visual Studio 2015 Community for free?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, vs-community-edition, visual-studio-community

I use Windows 8, I had Visual Studio 2015 Community edition installed, but I had some problems with it and uninstalled it. I can't download Visual Studio 2017, since I have some problems with my connection. I have an installation file dated from several months ago, probably the 2015 version, but It requires me to upgrade to Windows 8.1, but I can't do it on this computer. When I try to download an older version, like 2015, it requires me to login to my.visualstudio.com and on my home page it says that there's no download for me. I tried it with my prior and a new account and got the same thing.

So, since Community edition is free, why can't I use it?

Sorry if it's not the right place to post it.

Comment: If you have questions about the availability of MS products, ask MS. It's their product, and they decide when, where and how it can be used. VS 2015 has been superseded by VS 2017, and if they choose not to make 2015 available for Windows 8 that's their prerogative. Because it's free doesn't mean that they can't decide where it can and can't be used; it just means they're offering it at no cost under their guidelines. (And you have my condolences for having to use Windows 8.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a vendor support question about availability of a third-party product that should be addressed to that third-party vendor.

Comment: Thank you for response, I just saw that I had to join to Dev Essentials and all the products are available for me. But I still can't download it because of my connection problem. I think VS2015 Community is still free, the problem is my internet. Sorry for the lack of atention. Please, suggest me the right stack exchange for the question, so I can post the answer, since it's already solved. I posted it here because VS is a tool massively used by programers, I think SuperUser would be too generic for this question. Thanks

Comment: (And thank you for your condolences :) )

Comment: No, SuperUser would not be appropriate. I don't know of any [se] site that would be. You can post a self-answer to this post if you'd like (using the space below headed *Your Answer*). My comment still applies whether you found a solution or not; making software available for free doesn't necessarily mean *with no restrictions*. Open-Source projects have licenses you have to follow, MS says *free if you sign up and agree to our terms*, et cetera, and questions about those terms or licenses are better addressed to the source. (And you're welcome. :-))

Comment: And just to clarify, my question wasn't about the Windows 8.1 requisite not letting me to use the Community edition, but about the fact that there was no download available to me, and the Community edition should be there. And it is now, I just didn't pay attention on the Join Dev Essentials button.

Comment: Ok, I'll do that.

Comment: I understood the question. The availability (whether or not the download was there) is still not something we can deal with here. Microsoft determines when and how their products are available and when or where or how you can download them. This isn't MS product download or availability support. We can help with using VS, but we can't deal with whether you can download the version you want or not.

Answer (score 0):

I just saw it, just go to Subsciption when you are logged in and click on Join Dev Essentials button and follow the instuctions. After that, Visual Studio 2013, 2015 and 2017 downloads, whether it's a trial or Community edition, will be available to you.